# Top-home button portrait orientation in iOS6 simulator not working

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I set up XCode 4.5 and iOS6 simulator a few minutes ago.
My app supports all **4** orientations of the iPhone, 
portrait bottom and top home button, landscape left and right.

Well, I put that to the .plist as it is required by iOS6 and also the old shouldRotateTo... method is still there returning YES.

But in the simulator, the App is **not** rotating to portrait top home button.

Why? Is this by purpose? Would it work correct on device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, 
I found the answer now myself.

It is not enough to have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

in YOUR ViewController if it is pushed into a `UINavigationViewController`.
The `UINavigationViewController` also has to have those methods.
Preferably, you do this by having a small Category on `UINavigationViewController`.

This is my `UINavigationController-Rotation.h`:

```
@interface UINavigationController (Rotation)
@end
```

and my UINavigationController-Rotation.m:

```
#import "UINavigationController-Rotation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation)

#pragma From UINavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    BOOL result = self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;

    return result;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    NSUInteger result = self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;

    return result;
}

#pragma -

@end
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for iOS6 on iPhone is no Upside-Down orientation.

[from UIViewController Class Reference: The default values for a view controller’s supported interface orientations is set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations)

You can see this behavior also in Safari or Maps.

I tried to override this with UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll, like Dean said, but to no effect.
I decided not to use the upside down mode anymore, since it's kind of a User Interface Guideline thing which I like to follow and not to confuse users.

Comment: I am not in a hurry and really want upside down support because of the microphone placement on iPhone 3GS-4S.

Answer (score 1):

I think your viewControllers are going to return the default which is all but upside down. You need to implement:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

For all the viewControllers you want to support all orientations.

Comment: Does not work. Also did set all interface orientations in the plist, returned YES from ViewController's - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate and ...MaskAll from AppDelegate's - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window .

Comment: Does work as expected on iPad simulator. Possibly a bug in the iPhone versions?

Comment: I'll have to read the new documentation more. My expectation at the moment is that setting it in the .plist file and returning maskAll in the view controllers should do it. I recall mention of returning from the appDelegate as well. That may be the piece missing.

Comment: For me it was four pieces: 1) in my ViewController `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`, 2) the correct plist entries, 3) `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` in my ViewController and the last missing bit 4) the UINavigationController category (see my own reply). I already had 1)-3) in and it did work correctly on iPad sim, 4) made it running on iPhone ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else who is still having issues even after following Christoh's answer:

I just noticed the projects plist has separate entries for iPad and iPhone (Supported Interface Orientations (iPad) and Supported Interface Orientations (iPhone)).

Hope that helps.