# iOS 6.0 restrict auto rotation within a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

What else should I do?

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

My viewController still rotates.

---

It is embedded in a navigation stack.
If I subclass UINavigationController, and implement the same portrait-only templates there, and I embed my viewController in that tweaked navigationController, than it works, but I have no intention to rewrite my code everywhere a UINavigationController appears.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: you've already solved the problem, you must subclass UINavigationController

Comment: Thats what I've done so far, but I used presentedViewController instead of topViewController. Why should we "inherit by hand" these properties anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ORIGINAL ANSWER: No need to subclass - just do a category like I described in my solution here:
[Top-home button portrait orientation in iOS6 simulator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503658/top-home-button-portrait-orientation-in-ios6-simulator-not-working/12518577#12518577)

Basically, for iPhone the UINavigationController allows rotation for everything except "top home button portrait", for iPad it allows everything.

So either you do a category forwarding the decision to the currently active view controller or something static like

UINavigationController-Rotation.h:

```
@interface UINavigationController (Rotation)
@end
```

UINavigationController-Rotation.m:

```
#import "UINavigationController-Rotation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation)

#pragma From UINavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma -

@end
```

UPDATE: As Javier Soto pointed out, this might lead to undefined behavior if there is a second category doing the same. In that case,  subclassing might be a better solution.

In a situation where you know there is no other category doing the same I still consider this a working, low effort, local and pragmatic solution. I am not religious about that. Decide yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, just ask topViewController about it's own properties. If I wanted to restrict everything but portrait, I would unckeck supported orientations in deployment info.

Comment: Adding a category that overrides a method on another class results in undefined behavior, you should never do this. The fact that it works right now, is because iOS ends up using your implementation after the category is loaded, but this could change. Also, what happens if more than one category overrides the method? Just subclass, this is a terrible idea.

Comment: It worked/works fine on iPhoneOS 3.0 to iOS6.1.3. It works fine if you have to use third party components that you can not change. And my main reason for doing it that way: it is a single local change, while replacing UINavigationController by a subclass is a shotgun surgery in lots of places.

Comment: Also it is under YOUR control how many categories are overriding the methods - as long as you just do it once, it is fine.

Comment: No it's not. What if there's another category in a .a that you're linking in your app? You can't know. You should never override methods in categories, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You should inherit from `UINavigationController` and use your custom one everywhere. It's not that much work (just search for occurrences of `UINavigationController` in your code). This will turn out to be much more flexible cause you'll be able to customize other things if necessary.

**NEVER** do it in a category that overrides methods in the main class like that other response suggests.

Comment: It worked/works fine on iPhoneOS 3.0 to iOS6.1.3. It works fine if you have to use third party components that you can not change. And my main reason for doing it that way: it is a single local change, while replacing UINavigationController by a subclass is a shotgun surgery in lots of places. This might also include storyboards and other XIB/NIB files.

Comment: You don't have to change third party components because they manage their own orientation. Using a category to replace a method of another class leads to undefined behavior. Period.

Comment: @JavierSoto This is not correct. Methods in a category always override class methods. You only get undefined behaviour if you have two categories overriding the same method. (And it's not totally undefined, whichever implementation is loaded last wins.)

Comment: That is correct, but since when you add a category you can't know if something else will also add one, you should just never override methods. It's not undefined RIGHT NOW, but it can change, you would be relying on undocumented behavior.