# UIWebView shifting to the right Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

Please help, Ive got a PDF in a UIWebView, it moves to the right cutting off the border and some content. Putting the device into landscape and then opening the page containing the webview/ pdf causes this to happen. This happends on device and in the simulator.  Heres the code.

```
#import "waterTwoViewController.h"

@interface waterTwoViewController ()

@end

@implementation waterTwoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


double screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
double screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,   
screenHeight)];

webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:webView];


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WaterLineSizingValues"   
ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: FYI - for future reference - don't needlessly delete a question and post another just to fix a mistake. You can edit your question to fix typos and add additional information as needed.

Comment: Got it.  I didn't want things to be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you adding UIWebView twice to your view?

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];


[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Ok try this,

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width,   
self.view.bounds.size.height)];
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //check whether webview is the epicenter of the problem
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin; //so that the webview is fixed to the top left corner an expands on all other sides
```

Comment: Not sure why i had it there, good catch. I removed it and i still get the same effect. Anybody been able to recreate the effect. I figured out that putting the device into landscape and then opening the page causes this. Ill edit the question.

Comment: It Seemed to fix the problem but now it does the same thing when going back to portrait, but I am able to scroll over to the clipped off area now, still not right. Looks like when switching orientations the view is getting zoomed in on.

Comment: @Scrappy You should see the red color throught the scree now in both orientations. Do you?

Comment: Yes it gave me a red background. Got rid of the first line because is was already defined. I still get the same effect.  Im starting to think that a UIWebView is not the best way to display a pdf. Obviously I'm Very New. What is standard practice for displaying pdf's that are stored in the supporting files?

Comment: webview makes it easier to load PDF's trust me I have tested other ways and all of them are PIA.

Comment: Ok try to remove this webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; and try.

Comment: No change. Good to know this is the way to go. This only happens when starting the fisrt view in landscape and then going to the webView.  Entering the webView in portrait stops this from happening.  Id like to lock the first view in portrait and leave all the webViews alone so they rotate.  I found this but it did nothing. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954087/ios-6-0-restrict-auto-rotation-within-a-navigation-controller)

Comment: Ok do me a favor implement willRotate delegate method and add webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width,   
self.view.bounds.size.height); for both portrait and landscape orientations. I guess you are not declaring webView obj as property do it first to access it in all methods.

Comment: That didn't have any change either. But I did find the problem. (The pdf were the problem), I deleted the pdf's and added them back to the project.  Now everything's fine, really weird because the pdf's didn't seem to have a problem.  Thankyou for all your help.

Comment: @Greatwon :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted PDF's files caused the scale to fit to clip off the edge.  Delete and add back to project worked for me.

Comment: Correction. @satheeshwaran PDF's were fine still no solution.  It just started working. Not sure why, so I did something different so there wouldn't be any issues.  Here is code that worked better for me

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //name below (Webview) must be same as outlet
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    [_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];