# App in portrait - modal view in landscape - no autorotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rotation

Our app is in forced portrait mode. There is no autorotation and supported interface orientations are set to just portrait.

Now we need to show a "signature" view which needs to be in landscape. This should enter modally over the portrait views and needs to have a navigation controller and navigation bar. It should not be able to rotate to portrait, and when the modal view is hidden the previous view should still be in portrait.

I have tried using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
```

but that doesn't rotate the navigation bar... presumably because `supportedInterfaceOrientations` needs to return 0 for it to work.

Is there any way that I can do what I need? Using nibs (not storyboards).

Many thanks

Tom

Comment: You will be presenting/pushing signature controller or its just being added as subview ?

Comment: do you targeting the ios 6 only ?

Comment: @Jennis Presenting as a modal view

Answer (score 2):

just do these steps.

1. Make possible rotations in target.
2. Make a category of UINavigationController in your app delegate (I think your app is navigation base) like

-

```
@interface UINavigationController (Autorotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation   - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController (Autorotation)


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:["your view controller name" class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return  (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:["your view controller name" class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nope. It will work for IOS 5 too. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is prior to IOS 6.

Comment: This didn't work for me, could you give me some more information how to force the rotation? Many thanks.

Comment: can we chat? then I can help u better.

Answer (score 1):

its for iPhone

first supported interface orientations are set All Interface
then

in yourview.h file

```
      AppDelegate *appDel;
 BOOL isShowingLandscapeView;
 CGAffineTransform _originalTransform;
 CGRect _originalBounds;
 CGPoint _originalCenter;
 BOOL isLand,touch;
```

in yourview.m file

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
          isLand = NO;

appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_originalTransform = [[appDelegate navigationController].view transform];
_originalBounds = [[appDelegate navigationController].view bounds];
_originalCenter = [[appDelegate navigationController].view center];

[appDelegate navigationController].view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

//[appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0,20.0, 480.0, 320.0);
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(result.height == 480)
{

    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +60.0, +80.0);
    [[appDelegate navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

    [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(-20.0,00.0, 480.0, 320.0);
    [appDelegate navigationController].view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);
}
if(result.height == 568)
{
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +124.0, +124.0);
    [[appDelegate navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 568, 320.0);
    [appDelegate navigationController].view.center  = CGPointMake (284, 160.0);
}


    }


  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 }
  -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

  if(result.height == 480)
  {
    [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
 }
if(result.height == 568)
{
    [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 568, 320.0);
}

//    [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
 }
     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
     if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
       return YES;
    }
   else
   {
      return NO;
   }
   }
  - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [[appDelegate navigationController].view setTransform:_originalTransform];
  [[appDelegate navigationController].view setBounds:_originalBounds];
  [[appDelegate navigationController].view setCenter:_originalCenter];

  if (isLand == NO) {
     isLand = YES;

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
} else {
    isLand = NO;
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
 }


 }
```

Comment: Hi there, this works, and it works alright to be honest. The only problem is with the navigation bar - I'm getting the taller portrait navigation bar, and not the short landscape navigation bar unfortunately. Is there anyway to force it to redraw the nav bar?

Comment: try this one  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];   nd plz give me point

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow more (all your desired portrait and landscape) modes as I described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503658/top-home-button-portrait-orientation-in-ios6-simulator-not-working/12518577#12518577)

Reason: 
If your application only supports portrait, no ViewController can support landscape.
If your application supports both landscape and portrait, all ViewControllers can define further restrictions.

In all your ViewControllers' sources you can than decide on case by case basis if you would like that single ViewController derivate to allow portrait or landscape. You could also think about creating a common super class for all portrait ones etc. .