# Issue with Landscape orientation in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having an app in which is in Landscape mode.

As I am opening photo library from one of my views I want that view in portrait mode because photo library can not be opened in Landscape mode.

So I selected Portrait from my settings and used the below code to lock the Portrait orientation for all the views except photo library view.

This works fine for all the views Except the first main view controller when launches the app.

I use the below code.

For opening Image Picker in Portrait mode.

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2 : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

For locking the other views in landscape mode.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight ;
}
```

I works for all my view controllers except my first view controller when the app launches.

How can I solve this?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to restrict only one viewcontroller's orientation to portrait and all other viewcontrollers to landscape only? Try it using a category as mentioned in this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503658/top-home-button-portrait-orientation-in-ios6-simulator-not-working/12518577#12518577

Comment: I have already try this..but it is not working.

Comment: did you try [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; in viewWillAppear in a view you want to set it to portrait only??